# How to add Custom Attributes for SSO (Single-Sign-On) in .NET with Kentor.AuthServices

Tags: asp.net, .net, single-sign-on, saml, kentor-authservices

I am currently using the .NET 4.5 implementation of SAML2 called Kentor.AuthServices (see project on github). I am trying to go from my website, [MySite] to [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon].

I am looking to to send over 2 attributes, 1 called language that will either be en-us, en-ca, or fr-ca and 1 called employee_number that will be a 6 digit number.

However, I am stuck at this point, I have modified the web.config in the MVC implementation of the application (using the SampleApplicationMVC from github) and I can get it to send a SAML request to the provider [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon] (sorry if I use incorrect SAML terminology) but I am stuck at this point of how to fill in a employee_number field and language field.

I have modified the web.config file following the instructions to look like the one below, if anyone has experience with this help would be greatly appreciated.

In summary, I need to use Kentor.AuthServices for .NET to go from my companies website and single sign on to another external website that is pulling in SAML2 Requests. I need to supply the fields language, and employee number, the issuer ID is [MySite]. Thanks!

-Web.Config Start-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <section name="kentor.authServices" type="Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration.KentorAuthServicesSection, Kentor.AuthServices" />
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/AuthServices/SignIn" />
        </authentication>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>
      <kentor.authServices entityId="[MySite]" returnUrl="[MySite]">
        <metadata cacheDuration="0:15:00">
          <organization name="Kentor IT AB" displayName="Kentor" url="http://www.kentor.se" language="sv" />
          <contactPerson type="Other" email="info@kentor.se" />
          <requestedAttributes>
            <add friendlyName="employee_number" name="urn:employee_number" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
           <add friendlyName="language" name="urn:language" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
          </requestedAttributes>
        </metadata>
        <identityProviders>
                <add entityId="http://stubidp.kentor.se/Metadata" destinationUri="http://stubidp.kentor.se/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
            <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp.pfx" />
          </add>
          <add entityId="[BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon]" destinationUri="[BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon]" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
            <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/BenefitsSiteSSO.cer" />
          </add>
        </identityProviders>
        <!--<federations>
          <add metadataUrl="http://localhost:52071/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
        </federations>-->
      </kentor.authServices>
      <system.identityModel />
      <system.identityModel.services>
        <federationConfiguration>
          <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        </federationConfiguration>
      </system.identityModel.services>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Do I understand correct that: 1. User is logged in on [MySite]. 2. User should be redirected to [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon] and the identity of the user on [MySite] should automatically be transferred to [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon] using SAML2?

Comment: Thanks for responding. For Point 1, and 2 this is correct. The the [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignon] provides a SAML service. I need to send over the information employee_number and language with the message (containing issuer ID etc.) this service receives. How can I populate a employee_number field and make sure this field (employee_number) is the same as the employee number of the logged in user on [MySite]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In SAML terms, [MySite] is an Idp (Identity Provider) and [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignOn] is an SP (service provider). Kentor.AuthServices is mostly an SP implementation; which unfortunately not is what you need.

But, the components required for creating and sending an unsolicited Saml2Response are available in AuthServices. It is called unsolicited because the Idp sends a response to the SP without the SP ever having asked for it. To make [MySite] work as an identity provider and send unsolicited responses you should have a look at the stubidp in the Kentor.AuthServices source. It creates and sends Saml2Responses.

In this you would create a `ClaimsIdentity` with the user id and the additional information (language, employee-number etc) as custom claims. ​You can then create a `Saml2Response` based on that identity and send that with the help of a `SamlRedirectBinding` to [BenefitsSiteForSingleSignOn].

Answer (score 0):

Very useful info; also please note that kentor samples are designed such as:

1. HttpModule sample: for module & kentor config understanding (the module implementation is also used by MVC middleware)
2. MVC sample: for MVC middleware & kentor config understanding
3. Owin sample: for understanding kentor middleware
4. IdentityServer sample: everyone want this hotcake (uses kentor middleware)
5. All above are SP initiated so KentorStub sample: for understanding idp initiated (it uses MVC middleware (and MVC middleware uses httpmodule))

When you run 1,2,3,4 samples you get SP metadata (SPSSODescriptor) from `localhost:52071/AuthServices`
but running 5 gives IDP metadata from same link i.e. `localhost:52071/AuthServices`